# Subscriptions Integration with PayPal-PHP-SDK

Tags: php, paypal

I am using [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) to access PayPal API.

I need a "Quantity (user or seat) pricing plan", and I'm following this guide:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/.
The steps in the guide include those API endpoints:

```
/v1/catalogs/products
/v1/billing/plans
/v1/billing/subscriptions
```

I have found only how to create a plan(`/v1/billing/plans`) with the SDK, but I don't know how to add the parameter: `"quantity_supported": true`

I haven't found any examples/samples for `/v1/catalogs/products`,   `/v1/billing/subscriptions`

Can it be done with the current PayPal-PHP-SDK ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Updated answer (Jan 2021)

The PayPal-PHP-SDK was deprecated, and should not be used for anything at all.

The new Checkout-PHP-SDK does not support the Subscription API, so direct HTTPS integrations should be used instead.

You can perhaps modify or extend that new SDK to perform the REST calls you want.

Comment: Once I added an issue at github: `When are Subscriptions added to the Paypal-PHP-SDK" which was removed half a year later. So for Jan 2021 I can confirm that there is no integration.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60064508/1066234